# jQuery animate max-width overflow issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using a short bit of jquery which does nothing more than animate a div that appears to move from offscreen into it's desired location within a parent div.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{$(".tv").animate({marginLeft:"50px"},700);
```

In order to start off-screen I ensured the parent div would reach the side of the screen with a max-width value, and min-width value. I then set the child div to margin-left 100%, which I had assumed would be relative to the current width of the parent, but is clearly not. With the maximum width the child begins at the edge of the parent and there is no overflow problem. But, when the min-width is being used or the window is not as wide, the child still animates from the max-width position, and creates overflow.

```
.col2 {
position:relative;
max-width:1200px;
min-width:400px;
height:600px;
margin-left:0px;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}

.tv {
margin-left:100%;
height:224px;
width:374px;
background-image:url('image/tv.png');
display:block;
}
```

While I am aware this works seamlessly by using percentages, there is a column on the left side of the screen which must remain the same width, so as far as I know that isn't an option. I would also like to avoid removing overflow for the entire document.

I imagine there's a few lines of jQuery or javascript I could use to set the property of the child to match the parent's current width instead of the parent's maximum width, but I can't figure out how to measure the current width. Beyond that, I see no other solution short of disabling the overflow at the time of animating, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Setting your .tv to position:absolute will remove it from the box model and will keep it from resizing it's parent div.  Giving it a ridiculous left value will ensure that it is rendered off the screen at page load.

```
.tv {
height:224px;
width:374px;
background-image:url('image/tv.png');
position: absolute;
left: 10000px
}
```

Then using JS to animate your left value should give you the same effect without causing overflow issues.  Before it animates it sets the left value to the width of the parent div, so it doesn't start animating from the ridiculous left value it was initialized with.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tv")
        .css("left", $(".col2").width())
        .animate({left:"50px"},700);
});
```

Comment: Good thought, but it doesn't animate from the side of the screen this way(visually). With a width of 374px this causes the class to animate little more than 100px if the screen is shrunk. The idea is to make it move in as though from off-screen.

Comment: That's correct, I realized that shortly after posting.  The absolute positioning of .tv will cause .col2 to always stay at it's min-width of 400px.  To fix this, .col2 would need to have enough width to fill the rest of the screen.